# Can I split off a pipe to create an additional faucet in my basement?

Tags: plumbing, water, basement

I've been madly googling this question, but either this is not a thing anybody does or I can't find the words to express it well enough to get an answer.

I have a home hydroponics setup for growing hot peppers, and the faucet / laundry tub is across the room from the reservoir, which makes filling it up kind of annoying and unwieldy.

I have a PEX pipe that feeds an outdoor faucet and goes past pretty much exactly where I want it to go. Drainage would be an issue, since the drain is on the other side of the room, but since it's always going to be going directly into a reservoir, it doesn't really matter.

Can I split off that existing pipe and run another pipe to some kind of hydrant / silcock that I can connect a hose to without ruining everything? I have the basic plumbing skills to do the job, but I'm worried that it might be some kind of building code violation or that in doing this, I'll ruin the water pressure to my outside hose. Any clarifications on how best to describe this or videos talking about what I want to do would be very helpful as well.

Comment: What size is the pipe feeding the outdoor faucet?

Comment: 3/4", I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the main supply and connect the supply line(s) to the faucet. You will need a brass tee, crimps, and the connector for the pipe to the faucet, and some pipe.

If you want to use a silcock instead of a sink, you still need to attach it to something. I would start there (build something to hold the silcock), and attach the pipe to it once I figured out exactly where I wanted it.

[image]

Comment: @RyanAnderson This is a very broad question... if you post a picture, it might be helpful. If you have a more specific problem you are likely to get a lot more help here.

Comment: I'm going to do a little more research based on your answer, but it was more of a gut-check than anything. I'll have to figure out a place for the silcock and figure it out from there. Thanks again.

Comment: @RyanAnderson I added some images to perhaps give you some ideas... I'm not saying that these are great ideas, but they're simple enough.

Comment: sounds like it would work though +